# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopenblas in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, word2vec

I am performing conversion from word to vector using word2vec. While I run the program, I am getting the following error:-

```
4494 [main] INFO  Word2VecRawTextExample  - Fitting Word2Vec model....
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopenblas in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:945)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:750)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:657)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.openblas.<clinit>(openblas.java:10)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.blas.CpuBlas.setMaxThreads(CpuBlas.java:87)
    at org.nd4j.nativeblas.Nd4jBlas.<init>(Nd4jBlas.java:36)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.blas.CpuBlas.<init>(CpuBlas.java:11)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.CpuNDArrayFactory.createBlas(CpuNDArrayFactory.java:79)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.BaseNDArrayFactory.blas(BaseNDArrayFactory.java:71)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.ops.NativeOpExecutioner.getEnvironmentInformation(NativeOpExecutioner.java:1042)
    at org.deeplearning4j.models.sequencevectors.SequenceVectors.fit(SequenceVectors.java:162)
    at Word2VecRawTextExample.main(Word2vecTest.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no openblas in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:945)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:738)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Do you use maven maybe? Or some other tool which helps you resolve dependency?

Comment: Is the issue resolved now? I am getting similar issue.